# Replace HttpWebRequest with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Due to this reason, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11873#issuecomment-470611032

I trying to replace HttpWebRequest with HttpClient

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

using (var requestStream = await wr.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    await this.ZipFilesIntoStream(fileEntries, requestStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And I cannot find any guide on how to get the stream with HttpClient.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var requestStream = await wr.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    await HttpClient.PostAsync(url, new StreamContent(memoryStream)
    {
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await this.ZipFilesIntoStream(fileEntries, requestStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning the output of `HttpClient.PostAsync` to a variable, and calling `ReadAsStringAsync()` on the `Content` property?

Answer (score 0):

The code tries to use HttpClient as if it were HttpWebRequest. An HttpClient doesn't represent a *request* though. It's a class that executes different HTTP methods. The contents should be prepared *before* calling `PostAsync`, `GetAsync` or the generic `SendAsync`

I assume that `ZipFilesIntoStream` packages files into a stream. Since a `MemoryStream` is also available, it should use it as its storage :

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await ZipFilesIntoStream(fileEntries, memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position=0;
    await client.PostAsync(url, new StreamContent(memoryStream));
}
```

Comment: I did try this, but the memory will kill my server before it get post.

Comment: `MemoryStream` was used in the question's code. The scalable solution is to write the ZIP file to a temporary location and return it. If you want to write to the output stream directly, you can create your own content class derived from HttpContent and override the `SerializeToStreamAsync` method to write to the request stream. If you check [StreamContent's source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamContent.cs) you'll see that its main job is to copy from the source stream to the request stream in that method